# Encoding in buffers not associated with files

Tags: magit, character-encoding

1. I use Magit to manage Git repositories.
2. Some of these repositories have collaborators whose names contain accented characters.
3. In a freshly-started Emacs, everything looks fine.
4. In a long-running Emacs process, such accented characters eventually start being rendered incorrectly.
5. These characters appear in a magit buffer

   - which is not associated with a file
   - in a special portion of the buffer which is not accessible with the usual Emacs navigation commands, search commands, etc.

How should I go about understanding and fixing this problem?

Comment: Does it also happen in `*magit-revision` buffers (which show author names the main part of the buffer, not margins)? Checking coding system related variables like `default-process-coding-system` or `process-coding-system-alist`.

Comment: @npostavs Yes it also happens in `*magit-revision` buffers. `default-process-coding-system` was different from its value in new processes. Resetting it fixes the problem. So now I know how to fix it, but not what is causing it or how to prevent it. Do you want to turn this into an answer I can formally accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs decides how to decode output from subprocesses (like git) based on the value of `default-process-coding-alist` (and others, see [(elisp) Default Coding Systems](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Default-Coding-Systems.html)).  The default value for this variable generally works well.

It sounds like you have some package that changes it; if you have a recent Emacs 26 snapshot you could use the watchpoint feature to track it down.  Something along the lines of:

```el
(defun debug-if-setting (symbol newval op where)
  "Call debugger if setting SYMBOL's value.
Don't do anything if let-binding."
  (if (or inhibit-debug-on-entry debugger-jumping-flag
          (not (eq op 'set)))
      nil
    (let ((inhibit-debug-on-entry t))
      (funcall debugger 'watchpoint symbol newval op where))))
(add-variable-watcher 'default-process-coding-system #'debug-if-setting)
```

Alternatively, you could paper over the problem with:

```el
(defun use-default-process-coding (fun &rest args)
  (let ;; Replace the value with whatever you have by default.
       ((default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix)))
    (apply fun args)))
(advice-add 'magit--process-coding-system :around #'use-default-process-coding)
```